# GDAL Sentinel-2 driver

Tags: gdal, sentinel-2

Sentinel-2 images are usually provided in JPEG2000 format inside a zip-file with accompanying metadata.

A driver has already been coded and will be shipped with GDAL 2.1: [GDAL Sentinel-2 driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html)

As Even Rouault mentioned on the GDAL mailing list:

> You can also compile the driver code as a plugin against older GDAL releases
>   (works at least with 1.10 or later)

I would like to use this driver on a set of Win_x64 machines but have no means of compiling it myself.

Is there a way to obtain the Sentinel-2 driver as a plugin for GDAL under Windows? (possibly like the plugins provided on [GISinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php))?

*edit:*
For legacy reasons I am not yet able to switch to GDAL 2.1 so I am explicitly looking for a driver for GDAL 1.11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original answer is out of date. Don't use this for installing gdal now. The latest stable version is 2.2 and is easily installed from [gisinternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com) or via conda.

### Original out of date answer

Rather than building as a plugin for an older release, you could download and use a GDAL 2.1 development snapshot build from GISinternals that contains the new Sentinel-2 driver.  Both the [MSVC 2012](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip) and [MSVC 2013](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip) builds have it compiled in.

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.0dev, released 2015/99/99

gdalinfo --formats|findstr /I sentinel
SAFE -raster- (rov): Sentinel-1 SAR SAFE Product
SENTINEL2 -raster- (rovs): Sentinel 2
```

Edit: per Kersten's comment, below is how I added the 2.1.0dev python bindings to a python 2.7 virtualenv. This involves downloading and unzipping/extracting the standalone GDAL build and the Python 2.7 bindings from GISInternals and modifying relevant environment variables.

```
cd c:\temp
c:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\python.exe -m virtualenv venvtest
cd venvtest

SET GDALDIR=%CD%\release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver

REM Download complete GDAL/MS zip, not the core installer
powershell -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip\", \"release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip\")"
REM Extract the zip
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -orelease-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip

REM Python bindings included in the above are for Python 3.4. If you use 2.7, do this
powershell -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver/GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi\", \"GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi\")"
REM Extract the 2.7 py bindings MSI (note this doesn't actually "install" anything)
start /wait msiexec /a "%CD%\GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi"  /qn TARGETDIR="%CD%\GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7"
REM replace the 3.4 bindings with the 2.7 ones
xcopy /Y GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\*.pyd %GDALDIR%\bin\gdal\python\osgeo

SET path=%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\system32
call %GDALDIR%\SDKShell.bat setenv
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Temp\venvtest\release-1700-x64-gdal-mapserver\bin\gdal\python\osgeo
call Scripts\activate.bat

python -c "from osgeo import gdal; print gdal.__version__"

2.1.0dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. For legacy reasons I am not yet able to switch to >2.0. If switching to GDAL 2.1 is my only chance I guess I'll finally have to take the plunge.

Comment: @Kersten, you can easily run multiple versions of GDAL. No need to switch completely.

Comment: And can I install Python bindings for both, maybe by means of a venv? If that would be possible I'll gladly mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Kersten, yes you can. It involves some fiddling but can be done. I've edited my answer to show how I did this.

Comment: Great explanation!